# JSF ValidateRegex Allowing new line

Tags: regex, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces input text area with regex validation. I would like to allow the user to add an extra line. Here is my code for it. I thought \s allowed new line but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
<p:inputTextarea id="txtContent" label="Content Value" required="true" style="height: 100px;width: 250px">  
    <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="65535"/>
    <f:validateRegex pattern=".*[\s\w\d\.\-\']" />
    <p:ajax update="msgContent" event="keyup" />
    <p:ajax update="msgs" event="keyup" />
</p:inputTextarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) can be represented by line feed symbol, `\n` (Unix, modern Mac), carriage return symbol, `\r` (old Mac), or a combination of two, `\r\n` (Windows). This yields us the following regex pattern:

```
(\\r?\\n)|\\r
```

You can easily incorporate this pattern within the validator.

Comment: Is the double backslash required? because the rest of them needs to be single backslash to work. But I put in .*[\r\n] and it didn't work. Beside the definition of \s encompasses both \r and \n